# Laravel: Show title for groupby in view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to show a list of contacts, grouped by "type" column in the db table. I am able to show all of the contacts, but how do I show the title for each 'type' above each group? Should I use groupby or distinct?

**Desired output:**

Type 1 (as h2)

contact info
contact info
contact info

Type 2

contact info
contact info
contact info

etc...

**Table structure:**
Type|Name|Phone|url|etc

**The route:**

```html
`Route::get('/contacts', function () {
$contacts = DB::table('contacts')->get();
return view('pages.contacts', ['contacts' => $contacts]);
});`
```

**The View:**

```html
`@if(isset($contacts))
@foreach($contact as $key => $contacts)
<h2>type name</h2>
<strong>{{$contacts->name}}</strong><br>
{{$contacts->phone}}<br>
{{$contacts->url}}
@endforeach
@endif`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking up the contacts into your two types in your controller. Then pass them both to the view. It would look something like this:

```
Route::get('/contacts', function () {
   $contactsType1 = DB::table('contacts')->where('type', '=', 'type1')->get();
   $contactsType2 = DB::table('contacts')->where('type', '=', 'type2')->get();
   return view('pages.contacts', $contactsType1, $contactsType2);
});
```

You would then have two for loops on your page, each independent of each-other:

```
@foreach($contactsType1 as $contact)
  --- display info as needed ----
@endforeach
-----
@foreach($contactsType2 as $contact)
  --- display info as needed ----
@endforeach
```

Comment: There are 20+ contacts per "type"  and about 20 types. So there should be 20+ variables for each type?

Answer (score 0):

You can Group all types from your `contacts` table and query every type

```
$group_types =  DB::table('contacts')->select('type')->groupBy('type')->get();

        @if(isset($group_types))
            @foreach($group_types as $type)
                @foreach(\DB::table('contacts')->where('type',$type)->get() as $contacts)
                    <h2>type name</h2>
                    <strong>{{$contacts->name}}</strong><br>
                    {{$contacts->phone}}<br>
                    {{$contacts->url}}
                 @endforeach
            @endforeach
        @endif
```